# run loop in update() of spritekit, rarely, efficiently: a way?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

To present a bunch of nodes, one per frame, until they're all onscreen, I'm thinking to do something like this in the update() call.

Warning, pseudo code approaching:

```
update(){

switch presentNodes_inOrderOfArrayIndex {

case on
  if indexPostion less than arrayOfNodes length
    run Action to present node pulled from indexPostion in arrayOfNodes
    increment indexPosition by 1
  else presentNodes_inOrderOfArrayIndex.OFF
return

case default
return

}
```

But this is rarely going to be on and doing this presentation as a re-presentation. So 99.999% of the time it's doing an unnecessary check through this switch.

Is there a way to achieve this without putting something in update() that's getting called every single frame of the game's life, and is instead only active and doing its thing when needed?

Comment: Where is this update call from?

Comment: I was just wondering what is the point of adding nodes one per frame? I mean why do you need that? @Confused

Comment: @Whirlwind so as to get the appearance of them sequencing onto the screen, quite rapidly, rather than just being plonked onto the screen, all at once.

Comment: @MobileBen this is the update in a Scene, one of the gameloop functions.

Comment: @MobileBen I think the gameloop update in the Scene file is the only one available in SpriteKit, unlike many other engines that can have them overridden and called on many different types of objects.

Comment: @MobileBen I've just realised GKEntities can override the update function, so could create a "loader" entity that's instanced for the period of time required to load everything onto the screen in this way, and then removed. Is this right?

Comment: `GKEntity` does have an update. The reason i was asking was this seems to me perhaps to be a bit of pre-optimization. There is always some "bleed" that will happen. The question is does it really make a difference? You do have options. You can find ways to minimize or eliminate the test. Minimize would be having a singular test to avoid doing the brunt of the computations. Eliminate would be to either remove the queued task, remove the node, entity, or whatever you have which would make it no longer run. You do want something "intuitive" and easy to follow for you in case you have to revisit.

Comment: BTW, I have plenty of small test running in my updates that I don't fret. But I also disable a lot. I run periodic checks against performance so I hopefully get no surprises. But I'm fine with "transient" testing.

Comment: @MobileBen it's not so much about performance, I'm trying to understand how to think in terms of doing things for short, intense periods of time, and where I can do them, and how I can control them. It's the wrong word, but I'm trying to understand how and where I can "inject" operations for brief periods of time.

Comment: This example shows scenario where I can run a test, constantly, and have it do its thing based on a change in a state (case) but I'm curious as to whether or not there's a way to insert this kind of functionality on a temporary basis without needing a flag to be checked all the time that's acting like a light switch. Probably not in just SpriteKit, I think. It looks like adding GameplayKit and using an Entity that's only in the game "world-loop" for the period of time requiring access to the update() is the only way to do this. But I'm intimidated by the boiler plate required to us GameplayKit

Comment: Ahh got it. My bad. You could always just create a temp node/entity if you want to do it the SK way and have that run an action. Another way could be to make your own update queue. As long as that task is on the queue, it will get run with every update cycle. I use a combo of the two, but note I am not using SK. If you do the latter, you just need a "signature" for your update function that is consistent. One argument should be the delta time.

Comment: Sorry. Just about everything in your above comment makes no sense to me. I don't have a clue how, nor what is involved in making my own update queue.

Comment: Actually, I didn't even know this is possible. Does this mean use of CADisplayLink or some other OS timing operation?

Comment: @Confused I see. Well, personally I am a fan of SKActions and in your case, using them can be convenient... Like appzYourLife already showed in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that code inside the `update` should be removed.

You can try this

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let nodesToAdd: [SKNode] = []

    func startAddingNodes() {

        var index = 0
        let add = SKAction.run { [unowned self] in
            self.addChild(self.nodesToAdd[index])
            index += 1
        }
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.016)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([add, wait])
        let repeatSequence = SKAction.repeat(sequence, count: nodesToAdd.count)

        self.run(repeatSequence)
    }

}
```

Now all you need to do is calling `startAddingNodes` **only once**.

Comment: Hello appzYourLife, I'm sorry but are you sure it work "one per frame" ? Should it be valid just only for 1/60 frames ?. Also SpriteKit doesn't know how many frames are going to be in a second so the only way should be update method. P.S. I've seen your blog, great work man, nice project.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano: Good point! Actually I cannot guarantee the `"one per frame"` part. This is just an approximation.

Comment: This actually serves my purpose. I hadn't really considered "abusing" `forDuration` with such low numbers. But it seems like a perfectly good abuse of them ;)

Comment: You can always track your frames with a simple variable, then use customAnimation that lasts forever instead of repeat. With a check of frame - previous_known_frame, You can tell how many update cycles have passed, and add the appropriate amount of items,  once you hit the goal, remove the custom action

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: Without writing code inside the `update` method?

Comment: only code needed inside update method is frame += 1,  this is not something that is a bad idea to keep track of anyway

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: ok, yes it surely is a nice approach.

Comment: it is,  the real question is, is it even needed, because update is not fixed, this means you get irregular results,  same problem with your method, time fired is not guarenteed, so you may get irregular results (chances are they are not noticable, but we are dealing with pseudo code here)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: I agree, you should post it as an answer

Comment: LOL that is ok,  it is not something that should be done at all, the real answer would be a hybrid of your answer and my response to get the sequence timed correctly, and that is just too much work lol,  your way works perfect for things that are not restrictive on timing